# React JS - How do I optimize render code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code in my render function, but I have 5 different versions with minor html changes. I made new tables with each of the 5. How would I optimize it so I do not have to repeat a lot of html/js code?

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th className='desc-col'>Description</th>
            <th className='button-col'>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> { this.showData
        this.state.data.map((exp) => {
        if (exp.typeOfItem === "Asset" && exp.term == "Short-Term" ) {
        return <tr>
            <td className='counterCell'></td>
            <td className='desc-col'>{exp.description}</td>
            <td className='button-col'>${exp.amount}</td>
            <td className='button-col'>
                <Update expense={exp} />
            </td>
            <td className='button-col'>
                <Delete expense={exp} />
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
        })
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th className='desc-col'>Description</th>
            <th className='button-col'>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {
        this.state.data.map((exp) => {
        if (exp.typeOfItem === "Asset" && exp.term == "Long-Term" ) {
        return <tr>
            <td className='counterCell'></td>
            <td className='desc-col'>{exp.description}</td>
            <td className='button-col'>${exp.amount}</td>
            <td className='button-col'>
                <Update expense={exp} />
            </td>
            <td className='button-col'>
                <Delete expense={exp} />
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
        })
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show a second one? What are the changes exactly?  Based on this, I would suggest pulling it out into a component and passing props for changes

Comment: check the edit i made in the code, basically just the if condition on the typeOfItem and term changes in each table.

Comment: you can make variation as subcomponents/functions and have a function do the switching part. Call the switcher function to get function/component to render.

Comment: Hi Rahul, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull out your `Table` in a custom component and pass down the data as `props`,

Your new component would be,

```
import React from 'react'

const TableComponent = (props) => (
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th><th className='desc-col'>Description</th>
                <th className='button-col'>Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {
                props.data.map((exp) => {
                    if (exp.typeOfItem === props.typeOfItem && exp.term === props.term ) {
                        return <tr>
                            <td className='counterCell'></td>
                            <td className='desc-col'>{exp.description}</td>
                            <td className='button-col'>${exp.amount}</td>
                            <td className='button-col'> <Update expense={exp}/></td>
                            <td className='button-col'><Delete expense={exp} /></td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                })
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
)

export default TableComponent
```

Now you can render this component by passing `props`,

```
<TableComponent data={this.state.data} typeOfItem="Asset" term="Short-Term"/>
<TableComponent data={this.state.data} typeOfItem="Asset" term="Long-Term"/>
```

**Note:** If you have any other variable's to be used in `Table`, do pass them as `props` and in your `TableComponent` use them appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off splitting the array before the render.

for instance:

```
const assets = this.state.data.filter(item => item.typeOfItem === "Asset");

const longTerm = [];
const shortTerm = [];
assets.forEach((asset) => {
     asset.term = "long" ? longTerm.push(asset) : shortTerm.push(asset);
});
```

Next you can render it with a component you want

```
longTerm.map(asset => {
return <MyComponent amount={asset.amount} ... />
})

shortTerm.map(asset => {
return <MyComponent amount={asset.amount} ... />
})
```

And your component could be

```
function MyComponent(props) {
 return <tr>
   <td className='counterCell'></td>
 <td className='desc-col'>{props.description}</td>
 //rest
</tr>
}
```

additionally you could make a `table` component and pass it the collection which calls `MyComponent`

```
function TableComponent({collection}) {
return <table>
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th></th><th className='desc-col'>Description</th>
 <th className='button-col'>Amount</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    {
      collection.map(asset => {
         return <MyComponent .... 
      });
    }
 </tbody>
 </table>
}
```

and then the initial render would just be

```
<>
    <TableComponent collection={longterm} />
    <TableComponent collection={shortterm} />
</>
```